# Switching entire SharePoint to Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

How do I change an entire SharePoint from classic experience to modern Experience ?

I have already figured it out that once your sharepoint is switched to modern experience there is no way back to the classic one. You can only switch back and forth with lists and document libraries.

Do I need specific right for changing the entire SharePoint to modern experience? As it for now I have the right to change the experience of lists and document libraries

Answer (score 0):

To convert entire site to modern experience, we can connect the classic SharePoint site to office 365 group. Go to Gear->select “connect to new office 365 group”.

[image]

And after connecting to office 365 group, it will create a modern home page for the classic site collection.

Then when you open the classic site collection, it will show modern experience.

You do not need specific right for changing the entire SharePoint to modern experience.

Comment: what if I dont see anywhere "Connect to new Office 365 Group"

Comment: Please be aware that some sites can not be switched to modern, such as project sites or the enterprise search center. The reason why the project site can't be modern is that the Tasks list doesn't exists in a modern version.